# tensor of operators is Kronecker product?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, operator-theory, kronecker-product

Say $A$ and $B$ are operators on Hilbert spaces $H_A,H_B$ respectively. If the Hilbert spaces are finite dimensional, then I know the tensor $A\otimes B$ can be represented by the Kronecker product $[a_{ij}B]$.

Question 1: Does the Kronecker product formula $[a_{ij}B]$ still work in infinite dimensions?

Question 2: If not, does it work when $H_A$ is finite dimension and $H_B$ is infinite dimensional (possibly an operator on a non-separable space)?

Comment: You'll have to explain what exactly what you mean by $[a_{ij}B]$. In particular, if $A$ and $B$ are both matrices of infinite size, then this definition for a "bigger" infinite matrix does not make sense.

Comment: If $A$ is an infinite matrix and $B$ is a matrix of finite size, then $[a_{ij}B]$ makes perfect sense.

Comment: $[a_{ij}B]$ will be construed as an operator matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can make the Kronecker-product formula work in the following way. If $\{u_j\}_{j \in \Bbb N}$ is a basis of $H_A$, then we have
$$
H_{A} \otimes H_B \cong \bigoplus_{j \in \Bbb N} H_B,
$$
with an isomorphism between the two spaces defined by $\phi : H_{A} \otimes H_B \to \bigoplus_{j \in \Bbb N} H_B$,
$$
\phi(u_j \otimes v) = (0,\dots,0,v,0,0,\dots).
$$
Now, if $a_{jk}$ are defined such that $Au_k = \sum_{j \in \Bbb N} a_{jk}u_j$, then we have
$$
\phi(A \otimes B) \phi^{-1}(v_1,v_2,\dots) = 
\phi(A \otimes B)\sum_{k \in \Bbb N} u_k \otimes v_k = \phi\sum_{k \in \Bbb N} \left(\sum_{j \in \Bbb N} a_{jk}u_j \otimes (Bv_k) \right)\\
= \phi\sum_{j \in \Bbb N} u_j \otimes \sum_{k \in \Bbb N}(a_{jk}B)(v_k)
\\ = \left(\sum_{k \in \Bbb N}(a_{1k}B)(v_k),\sum_{k \in \Bbb N}(a_{2k}B)(v_k),\dots \right),
$$
which indeed corresponds to the operator matrix product
$$
\pmatrix{a_{11}B & a_{12} B  & \cdots\\
a_{21}B & a_{22}B & \cdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots}
\pmatrix{v_1\\ v_2 \\ \vdots}.
$$

Comment: Something I realized now is you interchanged the order of summation from the line $\phi(A\otimes B)\phi^{-1}(v_1,v_2,\ldots) $ to the next line. Could you explain why is that true?

Answer (score 1):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\End}{End}$
Yes, the Kronecker product formula works, and not just for Hilbert spaces.

More precisely, in the non-topological case, if $V,W$ are $k$-vector spaces with (algebraic) bases $(v_i)_i$, $(w_k)_k$ and $A\in \End(V)$, $B\in \End(W)$, then you can express $A,B$ using matrix coefficients $a_{i,j},b_{k,l}$ as $A(v_{i})=\sum_{j}a_{i,j}v_j$, $B(w_k)=\sum_{l}b_{k,l}w_l$, and then
$$(A\otimes B)(v_i\otimes w_k)=(Av_i)\otimes (Bw_k)=(\sum_{j}a_{i,j}v_j)\otimes(\sum_{l}b_{k,l}w_l)=\sum_{j,l} a_{i,j}b_{k,l} (v_j\otimes w_l),$$
i.e. the matrix coefficients of $A\otimes B$ are, indeed, given by the Kronecker product (with respect to the tensor product of the bases or $V,W$ with respect to which we compute the matrix coefficients of $A,B$).

Now, if $V,W$ are Hilbert spaces and $(v_i)_i$, $(w_k)_k$ are their orthonormal bases, then $(v_i\otimes w_k)_{i,k}$ is an orthonormal basis of $V\otimes W$ and exactly the same computation works. The only difference is that the summation is no longer essentially finite, but only absolutely convergent. I suppose this should work the same way in any context where "matrix coefficients" make any sense.

Comment: I am trying to understand your argument which would be great if it works in a much more general setting. I have to ask though: did you assume that the bases are countable?

Comment: @chhro: No, there is no assumption of countability.